# Protobuf Compiler Error When There's a Period in the csharp_namespace Value

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-net, grpc-c#

I am trying to add my protos to an existing common library so my clients and servers can import it and stay in sync with any changes.

I added Grpc.AspNetCore, Google.Protobuf, and Grpc.Tools to the project:

```
<PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.25.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.60.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.61.0">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

(but I'm pretty sure the only one needed is `Grpc.AspNetCore`)

I included the .proto file in the project, as both client and server:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Protobuf Include="./Protos/MyProto.proto" GrpcServices="Both" ProtoRoot="./Protos/" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I created the file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package myproto_grpc;

option csharp_namespace = "Projectname.Library.Namespace.gRPC";

service MyService {
    rpc Message (MessageRequest) returns (Reading);
}

message MessageRequest {}

message Reading{
    string id = 1;
    int32 value = 2;

    enum Polarity {
        Unspecified = 0;
        Positive = 1;
        Negative = 2;
    }
    
    Polarity polarity = 3;
    bool is_something = 4;
}
```

Whenever I build the project, I get the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
> Error   CA1708  Names of 'Namespaces' and 'Existing, Existing' should differ by more than case (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1708)

The kicker is, if I change the `csharp_namespace` to any value without a `.` it compiles just fine; any value with `.` in it - even something completely random like `Random.Name` won't compile.

I am new to gRPC and protobuf, so I might have missed something obvious.

**EDIT 1**
Interestingly, when I create a new grpc project from scratch in Visual Studio it builds fine until I change the `csharp_namespace` to `Whatever.GrpcService1` - then I get this:
[image: error messages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid issue, but I had a casing issue in my `csharp_namespace` that conflicted with other classes in the project.  So everywhere in my project it's `ProjectName.Library.Namespace` but in my proto I had

```
option csharp_namespace = "Projectname.Library.Namespace.gRPC";
```

... note the difference between `ProjectName` and `Projectname`.

Changed the capitalization to match and the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
   <Protobuf Include="./Protos/MyProto.proto" GrpcServices="Both" ProtoRoot="./Protos/" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This avoids emitting the shared part of the output twice.

Comment: No help - same error.  I've added another bit of info to the question as well.

Comment: It was a casing issue - see my answer.